# Showing category thumbnails in opencart 3 menu

Tags: menu, opencart, thumbnails, categories, opencart-3

I'm looking for a way to show the category thumbnail in the menu. Is this possible?

Specifically for OpenCart 3.

Answer (score 1):

**OpenCart 3.0.2.0, Default theme**

Open this file:

```
catalog\controller\common\menu.php
```

**Find:**

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

**Add after it:**

```
$this->load->model('tool/image');
```

**Find:**

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
```

**Replace with:**

```
if($category['image']){
    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category['image'], 30, 30);
} else {
    $image = false;
}
$data['categories'][] = array(
    'image'    => $image,
```

Then open this file:

```
catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\menu.twig
```

**Find:**

```
{{ category.name }}
```

There are three occurrence, **add before** first and last one:

```
<img src="{{ category.image }}" alt="{{ category.name }}"/>{% endif %}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Top menu with thumbs]

Answer (score 0):

for submenu use:

```
 $children_data[] = array(
    'image'  => $child['image'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($child['image'], 20, 20) : false,
```

or

```
'image'  => $child['image'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($child['image'], 20, 20) : $this->model_tool_image->resize('your-default-image.jpg', 20, 20),
```

in template

```
{% for child in children %}
<li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{% if child.image %}<img src="{{ child.image }}"  alt="{{ child.name }}" />{% endif %}{{ child.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

If missed something, follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310993/how-to-show-subcategory-image-in-header-category-men%C3%B9)